# Currency SQL data structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, currency

I want to develop a currency system on a custom forum I've been working on, but I don't know the best approach.

Should I add a new "gold" field to my user table and increment with sql statements?

`id, user, pass, created_at, gold`

Logic: user creates new forum post; update user table: `gold + 1`

**OR**

Should I add a transactions table that logs everything and do a `count where user = x`?

```
id, user_id, amount
 1        3       1 (new forum post)
 2        3       1 (new forum post)
 3       12      -5 (item purchase)
 4        3      -1 (deleted post)
 5        9       1 (new forum post)
```

**OR** is there an even better approach?

Comment: What exactly is the currency system used for? Like reputation here I'm assuming based on your examples? If disk space is not an issue, I'd recommend logging every transaction so that you have a log of everything. Users can get picky when you are not able to troubleshoot a reputation/gold/experience/etc issue with their account.

Comment: Well there is something known as [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Part of it means that you shouldn't create a crazy amount of columns on a table. But it also depends on what kind of data you're saving and what you will be doing with it in the future. Do you plan on having extra income days? Gold earning events? In such a case, a transactions table is preferable. But if not and it's really just gold, a column in the user table would be just fine.

Comment: I guess in a way it's similar to reputation. The idea is to increase "gold" by X amount each time a user adds a comment. If I have thousands of rows, does `count()` become inefficient?

Comment: Adding to the comments above, You could do both - the transaction log would show how the total was determined, and the user table would have the current balance for efficiency. But one of the golden rules of databases is to not store the same data twice. There can be exceptions where performance is critical for example, but they should be avoided unless necessary. So, if you only have one, keeping the log would be better (assuming that information is actually useful). And if there is an index on `user_id` it should be reasonably efficient to `select sum(amount) from table2 where user_id = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on what you want to do with it and which way to program you prefer.

To approach it with some facts though:

- I expect a forum to be fast. For that you should only use simple `Select`. Functions like `SUM()` take a bit more time to perform. In a small system that will most likely not be a problem, but mysql-db usually scale very bad, so you should keep that in mind from the beginning.
- You definitely want a way to track transactions. Mostly to be able to check what is actually going on. Even if you make a great system to deal with your gold you still want to be track what happened from time to time. For that it's handier to store transactions.
- Redundant data and transaction synchronization can be a problem. Every transaction system has the problem to keep everything synchronized. With MySQL that's not so difficult, as tables can be locked while you perform transactions. But redundant data is way more of a pain. You have to ensure that you change data everywhere at the same time before other actions can interfere.

On a basic system I would store the data in the user-table and keep all transactions as a log in another table. But never use that for an output to the user. For any further it depends on what your system needs.